# Модуль captcha в kohana?

Tags: captcha, php, kohana

Установил модуль captcha, от сюда - [github.com/kohana/captcha](https://github.com/kolanos/kohana-captcha), но все время выскакивает ошибка:

```
ErrorException [ Notice ]: Array to string conversion
SYSPATH\classes\kohana\arr.php [ 436 ]
431 $result[$key] = Arr::merge($result[$key], $val);
432 }
433 else
434 {
435 // Find the values that are not already present
436 $diff = array_diff($val, $result[$key]);
437 
438 // Indexed arrays are merged to prevent duplicates
439 $result[$key] = array_merge($result[$key], $diff);
440 }
441 }
```

могу распечатать дампы массивов если это чем-то поможет выявить проблему, а вообще судя по тому что сказано (Array to string conversation) массив не может быть конвертирован в строку.

**UPD** (выглядит страшно, не пугайтесь что много текста, это обычные массивы): 
выкладываю дамп массивов:

```
var_dump($val)
```

->результат:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(15) "DejaVuSerif.ttf" } array(48) { [0]=> string(2) "cd" [1]=> string(2) "tv" [2]=> string(2) "it" [3]=> string(2) "to" [4]=> string(2) "be" [5]=> string(2) "or" [6]=> string(3) "sun" [7]=> string(3) "car" [8]=> string(3) "dog" [9]=> string(3) "bed" [10]=> string(3) "kid" [11]=> string(3) "egg" [12]=> string(4) "bike" [13]=> string(4) "tree" [14]=> string(4) "bath" [15]=> string(4) "roof" [16]=> string(4) "road" [17]=> string(4) "hair" [18]=> string(5) "hello" [19]=> string(5) "world" [20]=> string(5) "earth" [21]=> string(5) "beard" [22]=> string(5) "chess" [23]=> string(5) "water" [24]=> string(6) "barber" [25]=> string(6) "bakery" [26]=> string(6) "banana" [27]=> string(6) "market" [28]=> string(6) "purple" [29]=> string(6) "writer" [30]=> string(7) "america" [31]=> string(7) "release" [32]=> string(7) "playing" [33]=> string(7) "working" [34]=> string(7) "foreign" [35]=> string(7) "general" [36]=> string(8) "aircraft" [37]=> string(8) "computer" [38]=> string(8) "laughter" [39]=> string(8) "alphabet" [40]=> string(8) "kangaroo" [41]=> string(8) "spelling" [42]=> string(9) "architect" [43]=> string(9) "president" [44]=> string(9) "cockroach" [45]=> string(9) "encounter" [46]=> string(9) "terrorism" [47]=> string(9) "cylinders" } array(6) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(29) "Do you hate spam? (yes or no)" [1]=> string(3) "yes" } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(28) "Are you a robot? (yes or no)" [1]=> string(2) "no" } [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(24) "Fire is... (hot or cold)" [1]=> string(3) "hot" } [3]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(27) "The season after fall is..." [1]=> string(6) "winter" } [4]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(34) "Which day of the week is it today?" [1]=> string(6) "Friday" } [5]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(34) "Which month of the year are we in?" [1]=> string(3) "May" } }
```

+

```
var_dump($key)
```

->результат:

```
string(5) "fonts" string(5) "words" string(7) "riddles"
```

+

```
var_dump($result[$key]);
```

->результат:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(15) "DejaVuSerif.ttf" } array(48) { [0]=> string(2) "cd" [1]=> string(2) "tv" [2]=> string(2) "it" [3]=> string(2) "to" [4]=> string(2) "be" [5]=> string(2) "or" [6]=> string(3) "sun" [7]=> string(3) "car" [8]=> string(3) "dog" [9]=> string(3) "bed" [10]=> string(3) "kid" [11]=> string(3) "egg" [12]=> string(4) "bike" [13]=> string(4) "tree" [14]=> string(4) "bath" [15]=> string(4) "roof" [16]=> string(4) "road" [17]=> string(4) "hair" [18]=> string(5) "hello" [19]=> string(5) "world" [20]=> string(5) "earth" [21]=> string(5) "beard" [22]=> string(5) "chess" [23]=> string(5) "water" [24]=> string(6) "barber" [25]=> string(6) "bakery" [26]=> string(6) "banana" [27]=> string(6) "market" [28]=> string(6) "purple" [29]=> string(6) "writer" [30]=> string(7) "america" [31]=> string(7) "release" [32]=> string(7) "playing" [33]=> string(7) "working" [34]=> string(7) "foreign" [35]=> string(7) "general" [36]=> string(8) "aircraft" [37]=> string(8) "computer" [38]=> string(8) "laughter" [39]=> string(8) "alphabet" [40]=> string(8) "kangaroo" [41]=> string(8) "spelling" [42]=> string(9) "architect" [43]=> string(9) "president" [44]=> string(9) "cockroach" [45]=> string(9) "encounter" [46]=> string(9) "terrorism" [47]=> string(9) "cylinders" } array(6) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(29) "Do you hate spam? (yes or no)" [1]=> string(3) "yes" } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(28) "Are you a robot? (yes or no)" [1]=> string(2) "no" } [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(24) "Fire is... (hot or cold)" [1]=> string(3) "hot" } [3]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(27) "The season after fall is..." [1]=> string(6) "winter" } [4]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(34) "Which day of the week is it today?" [1]=> string(6) "Friday" } [5]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(34) "Which month of the year are we in?" [1]=> string(3) "May" } }
```

Comment: Из текста ошибки следует, что каком-то из массивов `$val` или `$result[$key]` содержится значение, которое не может быть преобразовано к строке, а `array_diff` сравнивает как раз таки строковые значения элементов массивов.

Comment: это что называется "найди не строку".

Comment: по моему здесь одни строки.

Comment: а какая версия Kohana?

Comment: последняя.

Comment: кстати, решение там же github.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Аналогичная ошибка с капчей на версии 3.2.
Ругается на строку №87 $captcha = Captcha::instance();

```
        ErrorException [ Notice ]: Array to string conversion
SYSPATH\classes\kohana\arr.php [ 436 ]
    431     $result[$key] = Arr::merge($result[$key], $val);
    432     }
    433     else
    434     {
    435     // Find the values that are not already present
    436         $diff = array_diff($val, $result[$key]);
    437 
    438     // Indexed arrays are merged to prevent duplicates
    439         $result[$key] = array_merge($result[$key], $diff);
    440     }
    441 }
```

Решил проблему исправив в конфиге капчи последний массив на

```
'riddles' => array
    (
        'Do you hate spam? (yes or no)' => 'yes',
        'Are you a robot? (yes or no)' => 'no',
    ),
```

Кохана почему то не принимала начальный массив. А этот проходит. Но в итоге работоспособные только basic, alpha, word